# convert uitouch dragging points to custom logic of goal selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, drag, uitouch

Right now i am working on custom control for fitness related app following is the image of control i have developed so far.

[image]

the red view can be draggable vertically only from inner most circle to outer circle.

i have so far managed to drag view vertically from inner most circle to outer circle.

here what i want to achieve,

each circle represent 2500 steps for e.g. innermost circle is 0,then 2500,5000 till outer circle 15000

user can select goal in increment of 500 only

so i am stuck at how to convert red view's sliding points to steps

also i have noticed when i swipe fast i got irregular interval of current touch points so steps increment are low on fast swipe & high on low speed swipe.

any help pointing towards solution is highly appreciated.

here is my code so far.

[Circle Code](http://pastie.org/private/nkz7s9kjqzagontb7tn5g)

Comment: You can use distance of drag view from the centre of inner most circle to calculate steps

Comment: @VijayMasiwal can you look at my code i think i am close to solution but don't know what is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I would use an overlay `UIScrollView` for the red draggable part. And only allow vertical scrolling and set `pagingEnabled` to `NO`. And set its `delegate` as the viewcontroller.

Then, you can make your custom paging for 500step per page as follows by setting kCellHeigth to the number of pixels corresponding to 500steps in your image:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
    CGFloat kMaxIndex = 30; //=15000/500
    CGFloat targetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y + velocity.y * 60.0;
    CGFloat targetIndex = round(targetY / (kCellHeigth + kCellSpacing));
    if (targetIndex < 0)
        targetIndex = 0;
    if (targetIndex > kMaxIndex)
        targetIndex = kMaxIndex;
    targetContentOffset->y = targetIndex * (kCellHeigth + kCellSpacing);
}
```

**-- New Solution After looking at your code --**

I see that for iPhone5(width=320) the radius delta between adjacent circles are roughly 20 points. And this space corresponds to 2500steps.

`So 1 point = 125 steps`
Since you want 500 step increments, it corresponds to 4 points in the iPhone5/5s screen. Maybe when the users touch ends, you can try to snap the navigator to the closest 4 point grid:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    touchPoint = [touch locationInView:_navView];
    CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(_navView.center.x, _navView.center.y + (touchPoint.y - touchStart.y));
    CGFloat yDelta = newCenter.y - _navMinPoint.y;
    int yDeltaMultiple = yDelta / 4;
    int newYDelta = yDeltaMultiple * 4;
    newCenter.y = newYDelta;
    _navView.center = newCenter;
    _labelSteps.center = [self setStepsLabelfromNavView];
}
```

I didn't write these in Xcode so there might be typos/errors. If this works in iPhone 5/5s, then we will need to change `4 points` to a variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have to rebuild whole thing to test your code snippet & i have to deliver it before today end of the day so it would be appreciated if you can provide some solution using my current code i have provided code in question please have a look at it.

Comment: yeah, I realized you have posted code after answering. I am looking at it now.. It looks highly customized.